# Scrollable PHP Table

Tags: php, html, css

I am currently working on a website for a client, and the client specifically wants all PHP tables to be scrollable. Is there any way that this can be done? I have tried wrapping in a div and I tried adding it into the php stylesheet, but I am still not getting anything. So any help would be greatly appreciated thanks. It's a data table for live feed data.

Comment: What is a PHP table? A normal table? Does he want the table scrollable vertically to support a large number of rows on less height, or does he want it scrollable horizontally to support large tables on smaller screens?

Comment: `<div style="height:300px; overflow:scroll;"><!-- table goes here--></div>`

Comment: Php table.. please explaine xD

Comment: he wants the table scrollable vertically.

Comment: I got it to work. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you get some data from a database through php and generates a html table through php with the data in it?

Wrap a div around the table with the following css

```
div{
    height: 300px, // or another height
    overflow: scroll
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I also found a mistake in my code which also affected it as well. It works now.